# Pymysql python print the data

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

`cur.fetchall()`

I want to make folling data

```
((1, '28`c', '30%', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 4, 8, 16, 50)), (2, '30`c', '87%', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 4, 8, 16, 58)), (3, '40`c', '8.7%', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 4, 8, 17, 12)), (4, '20`c', '0.87%', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 4, 8, 17, 23)), (5, '-8.7`c', '67%', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 4, 8, 17, 37)))
```

to this:

`` +----+-------------+-------+---------------------+
 | id | temperature | wet   | created             |
 +----+-------------+-------+---------------------+
 |  1 | 28`c        | 30%   | 2016-12-04 08:16:50 |
 |  2 | 30`c        | 87%   | 2016-12-04 08:16:58 |
 |  3 | 40`c        | 8.7%  | 2016-12-04 08:17:12 |
 |  4 | 20`c        | 0.87% | 2016-12-04 08:17:23 |
 |  5 | -8.7`c      | 67%   | 2016-12-04 08:17:37 |
 +----+-------------+-------+---------------------+ ``

i use the following to make the basic first in cmd(win10)

`for item in cur.fetchall():
     print(item)`

but it showed nothing.

how may i fixed?

p.s. if the information isn't enough to answer , please tell me,thx.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `prettytable` package to print a nice formatted table.

In my example I add the headings when I create a new `PrettyTable` object. The rows are simply added with the `add_row()` method.

```
import datetime
from prettytable import PrettyTable

data = ((1, '28`c', '30%', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 4, 8, 16, 50)), (2, '30`c', '87%', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 4, 8, 16, 58)), (3, '40`c', '8.7%', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 4, 8, 17, 12)), (4, '20`c', '0.87%', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 4, 8, 17, 23)), (5, '-8.7`c', '67%', datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 4, 8, 17, 37)))

t = PrettyTable(['id', 'temperature', 'wet', 'created'])
for row in data:
    t.add_row(row)

print(t)
```

Output:

```
+----+-------------+-------+---------------------+
| id | temperature |  wet  |       created       |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------------+
| 1  |     28`c    |  30%  | 2016-12-04 08:16:50 |
| 2  |     30`c    |  87%  | 2016-12-04 08:16:58 |
| 3  |     40`c    |  8.7% | 2016-12-04 08:17:12 |
| 4  |     20`c    | 0.87% | 2016-12-04 08:17:23 |
| 5  |    -8.7`c   |  67%  | 2016-12-04 08:17:37 |
+----+-------------+-------+---------------------+
```